# Function object in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I want to create a list of functions consisting of function objects created by a fixed base function but with different input parameters. I have written such code:

```
def f_base(name):
    print "I am %s" % name

f_list = []
for name in ['A', 'B']:
    f_list.append(
        lambda : f_base(name)
    )

f_list[0]()
f_list[1]()
```

The result is:

```
I am B
I am B
```

But I want to get:

```
I am A
I am B
```

Can someone explain why Python produces such output and what is the easiest way to get the result I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you're doing with the `lambda` functions now is calling `f_base` on the variable `name` in the body. The `name` variable is determined at the time you call those `lambda` functions and *not* at the time you create each function.

The variable `name` refers to `'B'` after you finish looping since python keeps variables defined in `for` loops around after the loop is done.

This is particularly obvious if you do,

```
name = 'C'
```

after the loop and before calling the functions. Then you get,

```
I am C
I am C
```

To do what you want you need to create a closure function or, probably better, use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
import functools

def f_base(name):
    print "I am %s" % name

f_list = []
for name in ['A', 'B']:
    f_list.append(
        functools.partial(f_base, name)
    )

f_list[0]()
f_list[1]()
```

Which produces,

```
I am A
I am B
```

Comment: Also known as infamous '[late binding gotcha](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)'

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create closure:

```
def f_base(name):
    def closure():
        print "I am %s" % name
    return closure

f_list = []
for name in ['A', 'B']:
    f_list.append( f_base(name) )
```